# What does a 13 year old need to bring to the airport when traveling alone?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

My 13-year-old daughter is going to fly alone to another province within our country. What does she need to bring with her to get her ticket and get pass security?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is really going to depend on the country and airline policy.

Comment: As @PeterM suggested, you need to be more specific. Which airline ? Which country ?

Comment: @pnuts All flights require some form of ID; many buses and trains don't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby British Airways doesn't require any ID on UK domestic flights if you aren't checking a bag. [It is "advised" that you bring something with your name on such as a credit card, but in practice no one ever asks you for anything.] Same for Qantas within Australia.

Comment: You might be able to find an answer to your question in one of the existing questions about [unaccompanied minors](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=unaccompanied+minor)

Answer (score 5):

She'll need the same documents as anyone else. In Europe an ID will be okay, outside Europe she will need her local identification (passport, ID, ..., what is used in your country). Using her identification and her ticket, she will be able to get her boarding pass, which is used to go through security and to board the plane. She will have to go through the exact same procedure (cabin bag check etc.). Please consult your airline.

I know many airlines who accompany minors, in this case they have to report to an info desk, and an airline representative will accompany them through check-in, security, to the gate. Another airline representative waits at the gate when they land, and accompanies them from the airplane to baggage claim to arrivals.
Once at arrivals, they will only release the minor to someone who identifies himself/herself as the person who will be responsible for pickup (this is communicated to the airline in advance).

Please check this with your airline. If they have this service, they will also provide you a list with everything she'll need.

Edit: taken Calchas comment into account, thanks for the correction

Comment: This answer is not totally right. She won't need a passport if travelling domestically inside most countries, but ID may be required. For domestic travel in some countries (Australia or the UK) ID may not be required at all, depending on the airline. Some airlines treat everyone over the age of 12 as an adult (*e.g.*, British Airways).

Comment: @Calchas so how would a person without any form of identification pick up a boarding pass?

Comment: Note that in France, it was formerly not possible for a minor to exit the country with just an ID card. One needed either an "autorisation de sortie du territoire" (requested by the parents at the city hall), or a passport. This was abolished in 2013, but a recent law has restored this requirement, though it has not yet taken effect (waiting for the "décret d'application" to be published with the details). It is possible other countries have similar rules. Note that some countries may require proof (on entrance or exit) that both parents have agreed to the trip.

Comment: I forgot indeed that there might be other "national" identification documents, edited the answer to be more clear on this. Anyhow, you will need legal identification. Question asker said it was for a national flight, so papers to allow her to leave the country should not be needed.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Most people print their boarding pass at home, or download to their phone these days. At airports there are often kiosks to get them if you supply the booking reference or other details.