# What documents are needed for a child to fly within Canada?

Tags: air-travel, canada, aircraft

My daughter is going to fly on a WestJet plane from Calgary to Vancouver. She is not an accompanied minor, she is old enough to fly on her own. Is her passport good enough to get her past the check-in and security? She will be getting her boarding ticket at the airport. Will she need anything to get her ticket?

Comment: If her passport is current then yes, but for domestic travel just a provincial healthcare card is enough.

Comment: Next time please edit [your old question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74303/32134) to clarify, it will then be re-opened - instead of asking the same question again as a new question. I assume this question is still about the same 13 year old?

Comment: Note that I have not voted to close this Q as a duplicate of the linked one but rather to leave this one open and the other one closed as everything else requires lots of close and re-open voting as well as editing - leaving this Q open is the easiest and fastest way this time. My advice for future questions still holds of course.

Answer (score 6):

Westjet allows children to travel without an adult [from age 12](https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/travel-info/children/unaccompanied). They have an optional Unaccompanied minor service for 12-18 year olds.

Westjet's [ID requirements](https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/travel-info/check-in/id-requirements) for domestic travel state only "Identification required"

> must be presented during boarding at the gate and the name on the ID
>   must match the name on the boarding pass

The list of acceptable identification types, besides a passport, is presented on the linked page.

You *may* wish to call Westjet and ask whether they can annotate the passenger record with the More Assistance/Meet and Assist (MAAS) flag. I'm not certain this is suitable/available for this circumstance, but is typically used for mainly self reliant passengers who may need some extra help, i.e. elderly or young passengers.

It would also be recommended to ensure your child has some printed contact information for parents/guardians at both departure and arrival airports.

Interestingly, for others considering travel for children who don't wish to travel alone, Westjet also offers [Guardian Fares](https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/travel-info/children/guardians)

> The guardian fare allows parents or guardians to escort their
>   children, at a reduced fare, to their destination and then return
>   immediately to their departure city

Comment: You appear to have quoted "a valid passport is required" from the "international travel" section of the page you linked to. The travel in question, however, is domestic.